# Forms In angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Bit confused about how to use Forms(template or modal driven froms) in the angular2 beta.

currently i am using modal driven forms but getting some error here is my form.html:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="demo">
        <input type="text"  [ngFormControl]="demo.controls['name']">
        <input type="text"  [ngFormControl]="demo.controls['batch']">
        <div> 
            <input type="radio" [ngFormControl]="demo.controls['radio']" name="status" value="true"> Active
            <input type="radio" [ngFormControl]="demo.controls['radio']" name="status" value="false">Inactive 
        </div>
        <div> 
            <input type="checkbox" [ngFormControl]="demo.controls['checkbox']" name="one" value="one"> one
            <input type="checkbox" [ngFormControl]="demo.controls['checkbox']" name="two" value="two">two 
        </div>
        <select [ngFormControl]="demo.controls['select']">
            <option value="one">Oone</option>
            <option value="two">two</option>
            <option value="three">three</option>
            <option value="four">four</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="demoSubmit(demo.value)">Done</button>
</form>
```

and form.ts file is here:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, Control, ControlGroup} from 'angular2/common';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selectro: 'Form',
    templateUrl: 'src/components/form/form.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
})
export class FormDemo{
    demo:ControlGroup;
    constructor(fb:FormBuilder){
        console.log("Form Called");

        this.demo= fb.group({
            name: ["pardeep"],
            batch: [],
            checkbox: [],
            radio: [],
            select: []
        })
    }
    demoSubmit (){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.demo.value));
    }
}
```

so, my questions is:

1. which form is best template or modal driven and why ?
2. when to use ngControl and when to use ngModal ?

PS:- in this example i am unable to get the values of radio button and check-box selected am i doing something wrong, in this example i am modal driven form From [here](http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/)?

any good reference or example is welcome.
thanks.

Comment: This post is the best I've read on the subject. It covers everything you need to know about angular2 forms. The book is pretty good too. http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/

Comment: yeah i had go through this post but this post is not cover the part including radio and checkbox for which i am looking. do you know how to get the value from radio and checkbox as explained in my question ? any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-radio-group](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-radio-group) may help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got cleared some points related to FORMs in angular2 so posting as answer may help to someone !!

## when to use ngControl and when to use ngModel ?

Basically we can ngControl for both to get values of forms as well as for validations but there are some probelms using this methods so best solution is according to me use `ngModel` for getting values of the form into your class and use `ngControl` for the validation purpose. there are default validators provide by angular to check validation we can create our custom one too as per need and can use in the validation (ngControl). if we are going to create model driven form i.e we have to create new control for every input by using `new Control()`.
for the Control, control group and validation refer this best artical

http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/

here is the basic example of using controls for the form:

```
this.CreateGroup = fb.group({
            'name': new Control(this.demoInfo.name, Validators.required),
            'password': new Control(this.demoInfo.password, Validators.required),
            'select': new Control(this.demoInfo.select, Validators.required)
        })
```

Here i have three inputs named name, password,select respectively. and corresponding i have mentioned their values and validators (default validation).

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.name' ngControl='name'>
```

here is how we define ngControl to out HTML side.

## Angular2 FORM with controls and validation.

After a lot searching i concluded that using ngModel is best to get values from form. by using same it is easier to clear to controls of the forms. and validations gets easy. and used `ngControl` for checking validations.

here  is my working code for the form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id='myForm' role="form" [ngFormModel]="CreateGroup">

  <div class="col-md-7">
    Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.name' class="form-control" ngControl='name'>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-7">
    Password:   <input type="password" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.password' class="form-control" ngControl='password'>
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="radio" name='type' (click)='demoInfo.radio="Btech"' [checked]="'Btech' === demoInfo.radio">Btech
    <input type="radio" name='type' (click)='demoInfo.radio="Mtech"' [checked]="'Mtech' === demoInfo.radio">Mtech
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <select #selectOption (change)='demoInfo.select=selectOption.value' class='form-control' ngControl='select'>
      <option> select</option>
      <option value='One' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='One'">One Value</option>
      <option value='Two' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='Two'">two Value</option>
      <option value='Three' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='Three'">Three Value</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<div class='text-center'>
  <button type="button" [disabled]='!CreateGroup.valid' (click)="addNewGroup(demoInfo)" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</div>
```

and code for the class side is here...

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

class DemoInfo{
  name:string;
  password: string;
  radio: any;
  select: any;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES] 
})
export class AppComponent { 
  CreateGroup: FormBuilder;
  demoInfo: DemoInfo;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
    this.demoInfo= new DemoInfo(); 
    
    this.CreateGroup = fb.group({
            'name': new Control(this.demoInfo.name, Validators.required),
            'password': new Control(this.demoInfo.password, Validators.required),
            'select': new Control(this.demoInfo.select, Validators.required)
        })
  }
  addNewGroup(demoInfo:demoInfo) {
    console.log(demoInfo, 'whole object');
    this.demoInfo= new DemoInfo();
  }
}
```

refer this for working [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kEdeP54TEiZQxsnvrsiY?p=preview)
.

Comment: is this answer still valid for rc4/5?

Comment: @albanx please see my new answer below this answer for RC4 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38858229/5043867

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing that by ngModal you mean ngModel.

"1-which form is best template or modal driven and why ?" 
from: http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/

To create a new ControlGroup and Controls implicitly use:

`ngForm` and `ngControl`

To bind to an existing ControlGroup and Controls use:

`ngFormModel` and `ngFormControl`

Basically one is more convenient but gives you less control, personally I try to use template driven first because its more simple and less code, until it is not enough then I switch to model driven.

2- When to use ngControl and when to use ngModel ?

I don't know if you are mixing concepts here but ngControl and ngModel are not precisely meant to replace each other, ngModel handles the sync between input components and your domain/presentation model while ngControl handles the state of the form based on Validators, dirtiness of the input, etc, more geared towards giving feedback and allowing/stopping the user from submitting an unvalid form.

The ones that could replace each other are the one I mentioned previously in answer 1.

I hope that helps clarify a little bit?

As for the values of checkbox and radios, you only have ngFormControl's on them, add ngModel to map their values into your model. Once again quoting from the same page:

```
<input type="text" id="productNameInput" placeholder="Product Name" [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('productName')" [(ngModel)]="productName">
```

You can see that he is using both the `ngFormControl` and the `ngModel`.

Comment: amm i have already go through  the link for refer. you provided ...secondly will you provide any plnkr for the example ?

Comment: You can create one or a CodePen where it fails if you want, and I'll show you how to fix it there.

Comment: hehe i am bit lazzy in all that things still ill inform you when i created one using your method. by the way thanx

Answer (score 2):

Try using `new RadioButtonState(boolean, string)` in your formbuilder.

ex.

Template:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="doIt()">
    <h3>DisOrDat</h3>
    <hr />              
    <p>Choose</p>
    <div ngControlGroup="disOrDat">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="choose" value="dis" ngControl="dis">Dis                                   
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="choose" value="dat" ngControl="dat">Dat
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
```

Component

```
// create the form as a colleciton of Controls
this.form = formBuilder.group({
    disOrDat: formBuilder.group(
        {
            dis: [new RadioButtonState(true, 'dis')],
            dat: [new RadioButtonState(false, 'dat')]
        }, 
        { 
            validator: this.disOrDatValidator 
        }
    )
});

disOrDatValidator(group: ControlGroup) { 
    /* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
    if (group.controls['dis'].value !== group.controls['dat'].value) {
    /* tsslint:enable:no-string-literal */    
        return false;
    }

    // return null means validation passed
    return null;
}  

doIt() {
    // handle form submit
}
```

Comment: will you please provide any plnkr for the same ?

Comment: thanx for the answer but i am looking for the values using `ngModel`.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATED - ANGULAR2 RC4 FORMS

(So many changes are there in new forms so posting as new answer)

After the release of angular2 RC Forms there are lot of changes have been made in angular2 forms. there are some of them are major breaking changes some of them are negligible, here are some key points for using angular2 forms.

Basically there are two ways to build forms in Angular 2, namely template-driven and model-driven.
basic structure for using forms are as follows:-

- run `npm install @angular/forms --save`
- configure bootstrap method for your app as following:

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(), // disable deprecated forms
    provideForms(), // enable new forms module
  ]);
  ```
- use `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` to component directives to use forms functionality.
- create Form variable of type `FormGroup`
- Use `Validators` for validatiion purpose.

apart from this
**FormBuilder** is not a mandatory to building model driven form, but it simplify the syntax. there are three basic syntax/method provided by formbuilder are:

- **group**: construct a new form group.
- **array**: construct a new form array.
- **control**: construct a new form control.

These are the basic steps to use forms in angular2 RC.

Usefull resources for angular2 forms:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Live Demo for the same here

<kbd>[Working Demo for angular2 Forms](https://plnkr.co/edit/sUjE1ULYhfDHLNBw2sRv?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

My choice is using `ngFormModel` and `ngControl`, because we can collect form data more easily and can do validation ,etc.

See my [angular2-seeds](https://github.com/flyingzl/angular2-seed) project for more detail

Comment: unable  to start form.ts. i have to change in the gulpfile right ?

Comment: and also i want to get value of radioButton and checkbox which is not mentioned in your repo. i am totaly confused how to get the value of radio and checkbox using ngControl. hope you will help me

Comment: You've confused the concepts b/t ngFormModel and template based forms. You've used 'required' in your template but that should not be used if you are using ngFormModel and Controls. FWIW I'm still looking for how to properly do radio buttons as well...

Comment: I think the only people who know how to use radio buttons are those who wrote angular... and they don't have time to explain to us mortals how it is supposed to work

Comment: [https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-radio-group](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-radio-group) may help you.