# How can I close a modal in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I want user click the Submit button and the modal close automatically.

If I add `data-dismiss="modal"` in the Submit `<button>`, it won't run `submitComments()`.

I tried to do something like `$('#myModal').modal('hide');`, but not succeed.

So how can I close a modal in Angular 2? Thanks

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form (ngSubmit)="submitComments()">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="form-control-label col-sm-2">Comments:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
submitComments() {
    // I want to do something like $('#myModal').modal('hide'); here.
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your component code?

Comment: @SnareChops Hi, just a function submitComments()

Comment: So you don't have a `@Component` decorated `class`?

Comment: I have `@Component`, and in `export class MyComponent`, only one function submitComments()

Comment: Which button are you adding `data-dismiss` to? Are you submitting the form? or is this something like a cancel button?

Comment: I only have one Submit button, in this special case I don't want user to cancel. I want user click the submit button and the modal close automatically

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apart from the @MattScarpino's answer, another alternative is just to change your button type to `button` from `submit` and call your function
`submitComments()` and at the same time call `dismiss-modal`.
by doing so you are able to dismiss the modal and call function too at the same time hope this may help you.
here is example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="form-control-label col-sm-2">Comments:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="button" (click)='submitComments()' data-dismiss="myModal" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#Update

if you wish to close modal from your controller side you can use using this way

```
$("#myModal").modal("hide");
```

Comment: hey @HongboMiao seems you are working with forms of angular2, i would like if you answer here if you know the exact answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34350049/5043867

Comment: sorry i cannot really help, I am also new. I just uses some ngModel with <input> together

Comment: ohh its okay :) for more info about form i have posted this new question hope this will help you to learn something new. http://stackoverflow.com/q/35383765/5043867

Comment: Awesome answer, I was in the same boat and I was using data-dismiss just like this but my action was (submit) on the button, not (click), changing it like you suggest resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: How to close it only after success from Http POST method? if post give error I don't want to close it

Comment: What is `dismiss-modal` ?? You never define what that is.

Answer (score 34):

Using `@ViewChild`

add `#closeBtn` to the element with `data-dismiss="modal"`

```
<a><i class="fa fa-close" data-dismiss="modal" #closeBtn></i></a>
```

## Component html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="yourModalId">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a><i class="fa fa-close" data-dismiss="modal" #closeBtn></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

using `this.closeBtn.nativeElement.click();` to trigger click event will close your modal.

## Component typescript

```
import {ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    moduleId: ...,
    selector: '.',
    templateUrl: '.',
    styleUrls: ['.']
})
export class yourClass {
    @ViewChild('closeBtn') closeBtn: ElementRef;

    yourFunction() {
        //do something
        ...
        ...
        //close your modal
        this.closeModal();
    }

    //call this wherever you want to close modal
    private closeModal(): void {
        this.closeBtn.nativeElement.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a savior, simple and functionnal

Comment: seems neat and not too hacky like the jquery way for this case. thank you!

Comment: Worked for Angular 7. :)

Comment: Someone give this guy a beer. You're a life saviour man. Finally a solution. Thanks man.

Answer (score 31):

You can do it by simply declaring jQuery variable with any type inside Angular2 controller.

```
declare var jQuery:any;
```

Add this just after import statements and before component decorator.

Then access bootstrap modal with it's id like this.

```
jQuery("#myModal").modal("hide");
```

Comment: It'w working -> jQuery("#myModal").modal("hide"); once added " quote end of myModel. Is there any alternate way.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! Very simple solution!

Comment: It's working, but when build an app error should be appeared

Answer (score 4):

First, set the div's `hidden` property equal to a variable:

```
<div id="myModal" [hidden]="hideModal" class="modal fade">
```

Second, in the class, define a boolean named `hideModal` and set it to false:

```
hideModal: boolean = false;
```

Third, in `submitComments()`, set `hideModal` to true.

Comment: The modal popup hides, but overlay still remains.

Answer (score 4):

Perfect answer in this universe.........................

step 1 : give unique id to the dismiss button of modal

step 2 : after successfully submitted form or finishing task call

```
document.getElementById("addProductCloseButton").click();
```

in your class

Comment: This is not a good solution. You should rarely, if ever, have to reach directly into the DOM to accomplish an Angular task. This is a good example of bad loose coupling.

Comment: I spent a lot of time, after submitting button how to close the modal. finally, I got.  Thank you @pravash

Comment: No answer is working in my case. Even though it is not the correct way to do it, I will prefer this. Not a single answer working for me and found no documentation on it. Thanks @Pravash

Answer (score 3):

i use one of the answer and with some edit its work perfectly for me,
i hope it can help for try it change "yourmodal" to modal name that is your target 
you should use button Instead of i

```
<button hidden="hidden" class="fa fa-close" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeBtn" #closeBtn (click)="yourModal.close()"></button>
```

### Component html

```
<div style="margin-top: 0px !important;">
    <button type="button" id="openModal" #openModal class="btn btn-fab-mini btn-outline-primary" style="float:right" (click)="yourModal.open()"><strong>click here to open modal</strong></button>
    <modal #yourModal>
      <ng-template #modalHeader>
       <button hidden="hidden" class="fa fa-close" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeBtn" #closeBtn (click)="yourModal.close()"></button>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #modalBody>
        <yourmodalSelectorname></yourmodalSelectorname>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #modalFooter></ng-template>
    </modal>
  </div>
```

### TypeScript

```
import {ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
moduleId: ...,
selector: '.',
templateUrl: '.',
styleUrls: ['.']})



yourFunction() {
    //do something
    ...
    ...
    //close your modal
    this.closeModal();
}

//call this wherever you want to close modal
private closeModal(): void {
    this.closeBtn.nativeElement.click();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try not to include the form in your modal body instead add two buttons for the same in your footer section.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
    <label class="form-control-label col-sm-2">Comments:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a better solution. 
when you open your modal, save the modal reference :

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.open()
```

and then when you need to close the modal simply :

```
this.modalRef.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the easy step to close popup modal in angular 
in you component.ts file include these line

```
 import '../../../assets/js/custom.js';
 declare var closepopup:any;
```

the custome file path depend on your directory stracture

in custome file include this funnction

```
 function closepopup()
 {
  $(".modal").modal('hide');
 }
```

after this if you have condition on form validion event form data validated then you want to close popup modal
then include this line

closepopup();

if you still facing issue then inform me i will be there for you

Answer (score -1):

Just declare an id = "close_model" in dismiss button and put this code in the function where you want to close the model ::

window.document.getElementById("close_model").click() ;