# angular 2 - ngForm.value does not have ngControl members

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ng-submit

I have the following form :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'form1',
    template: `
      <div >
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
           <input ngControl="email" type="text" id="mail" required>                              
           <input ngControl="password" type="text" id="password" required>
           <input ngControl="confirmPass" type="text" id="confirmPass" required>                                
           <button type="submit">Submit </button>
        </form>
      </div>                    `
})
export class Form1Component{
    onSubmit(form:any){
      console.log(form.value);
    }
}
```

The problem is `form.value` has only an empty object and there is no sign of values of `ngControl` directives. Am I missing something?

Comment: you have missing ngModel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Forms :Validations, ngControl, ngModel etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383765/angular2-forms-validations-ngcontrol-ngmodel-etc)

Comment: that's not duplicate to my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining a `name` attribute in forms is a requirement, from **[angular.io docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)**:

> Internally, Angular creates FormControl instances and registers them with an `NgForm` directive that Angular attached to the `<form>` tag. Each `FormControl` is registered under the name you assigned to the `name` attribute.

So without name it's not considered as a form control. Also we need to use `ngModel`:

> The NgForm directive supplements the form element with additional features. It holds the controls you created for the elements with an `ngModel` directive and `name` attribute

So all in all, your template should look like this:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <input type="text" id="mail" name="email" ngModel required>                              
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" ngModel required>
  <input type="text" id="confirmPass" name="confirmPass" ngModel required>                                
  <button type="submit">Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You removed ngcontrols. Then what is the use of ngcontrol ?

Comment: `ngControl` would have been old syntax, prior to RC4 version when hastly googled... :) https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/07/15/updating-your-angular-2-app-to-use-the-new-forms-api-a-practical-guide/