# Angular2 and ngIf

Tags: angular, validation

The following Angular 2 (version 4.3.5) code does not work as expected.

```
<link 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ"
    crossorigin="anonymous">   
<script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<form style="margin:50px;">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input 
            ngControl="firstName" 
            id="firstName" 
            #firstName 
            type='text' 
            class='form-control' 
            required>
        <div 
            class="alert alert-danger" 
            *ngIf="!firstName.valid && firstName.touched">
                A first name is required
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Submit!
    </button>
</form>
```

When the `ngIf` statement is

```
*ngIf="!firstName.valid"
```

the error message `div` is shown when the page is loaded and remains visible after text has been entered into the input.

When the `ngIf` statement is as above

```
*ngIf="!firstName.valid && firstName.touched"
```

the error message is not shown.

What am I missing?
thank you A.G.

Comment: You have imported the ´FormsModule´, not the ´ReactiveFormsModule´, right? Try to replace ngControl by [(ngModel)] and add a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify what type of template variable that # refers to by putting ="ngControl" or ="ngModel"

```
<input ngControl="firstName" 
        id="firstName" 
        #firstName="ngForm"   // or ngModel if you're using 2-way binding
        type='text' 
        class='form-control' 
        required>
    <div 
        class="alert alert-danger" 
        *ngIf="!firstName.valid && firstName.touched">
            A first name is required
    </div>
```

See here: [Angular2 Forms :Validations, ngControl, ngModel etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383765/angular2-forms-validations-ngcontrol-ngmodel-etc)

Comment: I've tried using
 #firstName="ngForm"
and see the following error using the browser's developer's tools.
`code`
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("     <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input ngControl="firstName" id="firstName" [ERROR ->]#firstName="ngForm" type='text' class='form-control' required>
        ...

When the directive is added to the component

 @Component({
          ...
   exportAs : 'ngForm'
 })

the same error occurs.

Comment: Have you imported ngForm in the component? A plunker would help. I think for ngForm / ngModel / ngControl to work properly, they need to be wrapped in an ngForm element. 

        <form #f="ngForm">
...rest of your form here.... 
         </form>

If you do it like that, "f" is the name of your ngForm object, and then you can access properties inside it like 
f.firstName,  etc.

Answer (score 0):

added a class Contact with firstName and comment properties
imported FormsModule in app.module.ts
add property and initialized model of type Contact to ContactFormComponent type

```
<form #contactForm='ngForm' style='margin:50px;'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='firstName'>First Name</label>
        <br />
        <input id='firstName' type='text' class='form-control' [(ngModel)]='model.firstName' required name='firstName' #firstName="ngModel"
            (change)='onChange(ngModel)'>
        <div [hidden]="firstName.valid || firstName.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            A first name is required.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='comment'>Comment</label>
        <br />
        <textarea id='comment' class='form-control' [(ngModel)]='model.comment' required name='comment' #comment="ngModel" ></textarea>
        <div [hidden]="comment.valid || comment.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            A comment is required.
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>
         Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

The changes were made after following the example at https://angular.io/guide/forms and now the component works as expected.