# Close Bootstrap 4 modal on submit event in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm working on an Angular 4 application with Bootstrap 4.

I have implemented a bootstrap modal component which works fine. On click it shows and clicking on cross closes it.

The modal contain a form to add a user.

[image]

And on clicking on **Add User** button adds the user properly.

All I want is to close the modal if users added success fully.

I used `onSubmit()` function in Angular component:

```
onSubmit({value, valid}) {
    if (valid) {
      console.log(value);
      this.formInvalid = false;
      this.userMeta = value;
      this.allUsers.unshift(this.userMeta);
    } else {
      console.log('Form is invalid!', valid);
      this.formInvalid = true;
    }
  }
```

So is there any way I can close the modal in this function?

Comment: Have you included jquery in your pages? I think you would have as you are using bootstrap.

Comment: yes I have included it through `.angular-cli.json` file ... something like this: `"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",`

Answer (score 3):

Presuming you are using the project [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) (which you should be to use bootstrap components with Angular, rather than jQuery)

In the modal component you can grab a reference to itself via dependency injection:

`constructor(public modal: NgbActiveModal) { }`

Then you can use the appropriate methods:

`modal.dismiss()` to close with an error/reason.

`modal.close(something)` to close with a result, your `userMeta` for example - whatever you want to return.

---

If you're using standard Bootstrap with the jQuery dependency instead of the Angular version, you should just be able to use `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` as described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#methods).

Comment: :( I wish I used ng-bootstrap ... Now I have used Standard bootstrap How can I close the modal from my typescript code?

Comment: One more question Uncle ... Can switch to ng-bootstrap?

Comment: The 2nd part of the answer explains how to do it with standard jQuery. Switching to ng-bootstrap at this point won't be too easy, you'll have to rewrite all usages of bootstrap components such as modals.

Comment: Actually second part explains how to do it with jQuery `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` I don't think I can use `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` piece of code in my TS file.

Comment: Your reply to Himanshu Upadhyay confirms you have jquery included in your project, so you should be able to use it. How did you open the modal?

Comment: I'm opening the modal with a button like this: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark add-new" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal">Add User </button>` using `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal"`

Comment: These attributes actually use jQuery under the hood to do what they do, there's a similar attribute you can put on your modal buttons to close it, but obviously that won't allow you to close the modal only if your angular code executes successfully. I would try the jQuery solution, if it doesn't work show the error.

Comment: So how can we use jQuery in our TS file?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library - `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` is just Javascript and should work perfectly fine in any TS file, provided jQuery is available.

Comment: Ok trying it :)

Comment: It gives me an error if I try to add `$` or `jQuery` in my TS file.

Comment: Do I have to import jQuery first?

Comment: As with all external dependencies in typescript yes, try `import * as $ from 'jquery'` at the top of your file.

Comment: I have successfully added jQuery in the TS file with your suggestion. But when I try to call `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` its shows an error. **UsersComponent.html:60 ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery__(...).modal is not a function** because .modal is not a jQuery function.

Comment: Is this a compilation error or a runtime error? You may also need to `import 'bootstrap'` after jQuery.

Comment: Do you have bootstrap's js file imported in your `.angular-cli.json` after jQuery?

Comment: Actually I made it work with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354041/how-can-i-close-a-modal-in-angular-2 .... Is this the right approach?

Comment: This is fine as long as your `onSubmit` function has no failure case. Since it closes the modal and calls the function at the same time - if the function fails it doesn't care, the modal will still close.

Comment: Actually its mimicking the click event. If we can figure out a proper way then it would be nice. :)

Comment: Your issue is that the bootstrap jquery functions aren't being registered for some reason. My last suggestion would be to install the type definitions and see if it helps: `npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap`

Comment: Na! didn't work... But my editor seems to read the .modal() function now... Same error on runtime. BTW what is @types/bootstrap

Comment: It's a typescript definition package that exists to let typescript know what types are added by bootstrap. As the bootstrap library is javascript, it doesn't have these by default. For some reason it seems as if your jQuery object is not being augmented with bootstrap's new functions

Comment: Yeah... So I guess I have to stick with '@ViewChild` and `ElementRef` for now. Thanks for your time Uncle :)