# Angular2 Form Validation Inside Component

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, input, angular

I need to add a model drive form validation to my custom input component.
I'm not sure how to implement it passing `ngControl` to my component.

In my plunkr example `http://plnkr.co/edit/QTmxl8ij5Z6E3xKh45hI?p=preview` there are first two input tags which are working and then there is the `my-form-input` which should do the same thing as the first two inputs, but using a custom component

```
      <form [ngFormModel]="loginForm">
        <p>
          <input type="text" ngControl="usernameX" required placeholder="usernameX" /><br>
          valid {{usernameX.valid}}
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="text" ngControl="passwordX" required placeholder="passwordX"/><br>
          valid {{passwordX.valid}}
        </p>

        <my-form-input [placeholder]="'usernameXX'" [required]="true" [control]="usernameXX"></my-form-input><br>
        valid {{usernameXX.valid}}

        <p>form is valid: {{loginForm.valid}}</p>
      </form>
```

here is only a idea of my component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-input',
  directives: [ FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>
        <input type="text" [attr.placeholder]="placeholder" [attr.required]="required" [attr.ngControl]="control"/><br>
        valid {{control.valid}}
      </p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() required: boolean;
  @Input() control: Control;
```

thx

Answer (score 1):

## Angular2 FORM with controls and validation.

After a lot searching i concluded that using ngModel is best to get values from form. by using same it is easier to clear to controls of the forms. and validations gets easy. and used `ngControl` for checking validations.

here  is my working code for the form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id='myForm' role="form" [ngFormModel]="CreateGroup">

  <div class="col-md-7">
    Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.name' class="form-control" ngControl='name'>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
    Password:   <input type="password" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.password' class="form-control" ngControl='password'>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="radio" name='type' (click)='demoInfo.radio="Btech"' [checked]="'Btech' === demoInfo.radio">Btech
    <input type="radio" name='type' (click)='demoInfo.radio="Mtech"' [checked]="'Mtech' === demoInfo.radio">Mtech
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
    <select #selectOption (change)='demoInfo.select=selectOption.value' class='form-control' ngControl='select'>
      <option> select</option>
      <option value='One' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='One'">One Value</option>
      <option value='Two' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='Two'">two Value</option>
      <option value='Three' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='Three'">Three Value</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<div class='text-center'>
  <button type="button" [disabled]='!CreateGroup.valid' (click)="addNewGroup(demoInfo)" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</div>
```

and code for the class side is here...

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

class DemoInfo{
  name:string;
  password: string;
  radio: any;
  select: any;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES] 
})
export class AppComponent { 
  CreateGroup: FormBuilder;
  demoInfo: DemoInfo;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
    this.demoInfo= new DemoInfo(); 

    this.CreateGroup = fb.group({
            'name': new Control(this.demoInfo.name, Validators.required),
            'password': new Control(this.demoInfo.password, Validators.required),
            'select': new Control(this.demoInfo.select, Validators.required)
        })
  }
  addNewGroup(demoInfo:demoInfo) {
    console.log(demoInfo, 'whole object');
    this.demoInfo= new DemoInfo();
  }
}
```

refer this for working [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kEdeP54TEiZQxsnvrsiY?p=preview)
.

For more details refer here

- [Forms In angular2 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35673741/5043867)

Comment: hi, that's exactly the same thing I do on my example! My problem is, how to I pass ngControl to input if the input is wrapped by an other component, in my case <my-form-input>