# Form Submission in Angular2.0

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am just start learning angular 2.0.I have problem while submitting the forms,The Url where I learn forms:

http://learnangular2.com/forms/

here is my code:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="loginForm" (submit)="doLogin($event)">
    <input ngControl="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
    <input ngControl="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password">
  <button type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Javascript Part:

```
import {Component,FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/form.component.html'
})
export class FormComponent {

doLogin(event){
console.log(this.loginForm.value);

}

};
```

Main.ts is:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Error is:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.form is undefined in [loginForm in FormComponent@6:6]
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You don't have a property called `loginForm` in the class `FormComponent`.

Comment: can you plaese tell me how can i solve this

Comment: See the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFormModel-directive.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Angular2 FORM with controls and validation.

After a lot searching i concluded that using ngModel is best to get values from form. by using same it is easier to clear to controls of the forms. and validations gets easy. and used `ngControl` for checking validations.

here  is my working code for the form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id='myForm' role="form" [ngFormModel]="CreateGroup">

  <div class="col-md-7">
    Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.name' class="form-control" ngControl='name'>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
    Password:   <input type="password" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.password' class="form-control" ngControl='password'>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="radio" name='type' (click)='demoInfo.radio="Btech"' [checked]="'Btech' === demoInfo.radio">Btech
    <input type="radio" name='type' (click)='demoInfo.radio="Mtech"' [checked]="'Mtech' === demoInfo.radio">Mtech
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
    <select #selectOption (change)='demoInfo.select=selectOption.value' class='form-control' ngControl='select'>
      <option> select</option>
      <option value='One' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='One'">One Value</option>
      <option value='Two' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='Two'">two Value</option>
      <option value='Three' [selected]="demoInfo.select==='Three'">Three Value</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<div class='text-center'>
  <button type="button" [disabled]='!CreateGroup.valid' (click)="addNewGroup(demoInfo)" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</div>
```

and code for the class side is here...

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

class DemoInfo{
  name:string;
  password: string;
  radio: any;
  select: any;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES] 
})
export class AppComponent { 
  CreateGroup: FormBuilder;
  demoInfo: DemoInfo;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
    this.demoInfo= new DemoInfo(); 

    this.CreateGroup = fb.group({
            'name': new Control(this.demoInfo.name, Validators.required),
            'password': new Control(this.demoInfo.password, Validators.required),
            'select': new Control(this.demoInfo.select, Validators.required)
        })
  }
  addNewGroup(demoInfo:demoInfo) {
    console.log(demoInfo, 'whole object');
    this.demoInfo= new DemoInfo();
  }
}
```

refer this for working [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kEdeP54TEiZQxsnvrsiY?p=preview)
.

see also -

- [Forms In angular2 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34350049/5043867)
- http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/
- http://blog.jhades.org/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Answer (score 2):

You still need to learn about `ControlGroup,FormBuilder`. This will fix your problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jqrVirudY8anJxTMUjTP?p=preview

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES,CORE_DIRECTIVES,FormBuilder, Validators,Control,ControlGroup } from 'angular2/common';

export class FormComponent {

loginForm: ControlGroup;

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
       this.loginForm = new ControlGroup({
            login: new Control(""),
            password: new Control("")
       });
}
doLogin(event){
console.log(this.loginForm.value);
}
```

article : http://blog.jhades.org/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/ - start learning...

Comment: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'FormComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'FormComponent' is decorated with Injectable.

Comment: You need to Import `ControlGroup,FormBuilder` before you use them. Check my update.

Comment: Here In my update I'm not using `formBuilder` But you will have to learn it if you start with `Form` in Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    //create ControlGroup
    this.loginForm = new ControlGroup({
     email: new Control(""),
     password: new Control("")
   });
  }

  doLogin(event){
console.log(this.loginForm.value);

}
}
```

This may help you: [NgFormModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFormModel-directive.html)